# Position relative with bottom not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am able to position one div from top,but when i am using `bottom :20%` is not working. I tried to give `position:fixed` to that div where i used `bottom: 20%` that time div height increases if I am dragging.

```js
$( function() {
  $( "#draggable1,#draggable2" ).draggable({ containment: "#containment-wrapper", scroll: false });
});
```

```css
#containment-wrapper {
    width: 95%;
    height: 400px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
}

h3 {
    clear: left;
}

.draggable {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

#draggable1 {
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid black;
    top: 20%;
}

#draggable2 {
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid black;
    bottom: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="containment-wrapper">
  <div id="draggable1" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
    <p>I'm from top 20%</p>
  </div>
 
  <div class="draggable ui-widget-content">
    <p id="draggable2" class="ui-widget-header">I'm from bottom 20%</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what is the expected result

Comment: Take another look at your elements and the selectors you've declared for them - I get the impression that certain classes and IDs are attributed to the wrong elements (i.e: nested elements instead of parent elements).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you.

```js
$( function() {
  $( "#draggable1,#draggable2" ).draggable({ containment: "#containment-wrapper", scroll: false });
});
```

```css
#containment-wrapper {
    width: 95%;
    height: 400px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

h3 {
    clear: left;
}

.draggable {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

#draggable1 {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid black;
    top: 20%;
}

#draggable2 {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid black;
    bottom: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="containment-wrapper">
  <div id="draggable1" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
    <p>I'm from top 20%</p>
  </div>
 
  <div id="draggable2" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
    <p>I'm from bottom 20%</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `#containment-wrapper` `position:relative` and there child's as `position:absolute`

```js
$( function() {
  $( "#draggable1,#draggable2" ).draggable({ containment: "#containment-wrapper", scroll: false });
});
```

```css
#containment-wrapper {
  position: relative;
    width: 95%;
    height: 400px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

h3 {
    clear: left;
}

.draggable {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    padding: 0.5em;   
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

#draggable1 {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid black;
    top: 20%;
}

#draggable2 {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid black;   
    left: 20%;
    bottom: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="containment-wrapper">
  
  <div id="draggable1" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
    <p>I'm from top 20%</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="draggable2" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
    <p>I'm from bottom 20%</p>
  </div>
 
  
</div>
```